# Looping audio in midijs?

Tags: javascript, midi

I'm trying to use [MIDIjs](http://midijs.net) to play audio (specifically because I'm using [WAD.js](https://github.com/jmickle66666666/wad-js), which uses it). Unfortunately I can't figure out how to loop audio, there's a frustrating lack of documentation, and I'm not finding anything in the source code. At the very least I'd like to know when the file has naturally ended to restart using `MIDIjs.play()`, but I'm not even seeing anything for that.

I'd appreciate it if someone pointed me towards a solution, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue and wasn't entirely satisfied with the workaround in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68676135/382130) because of how it reloaded the file every time the url was passed into a MIDIjs function and it seemed to loop slightly too early.

So, I started digging into the [MIDIjs source](https://www.midijs.net/lib/midi.js), which also has a [map file](https://www.midijs.net/lib/midi.js.map), but I didn't bother trying to maximize/deobfuscate it. I noticed a couple mentions of `loop` that are set by second parameter `t` in function `X`. I wasn't sure, but thought maybe `X` was `play`, so I tried it.

```
MIDIjs.play(url, true);
```

It worked!

Since I'm working with Kotlin/JS, here's my `external` code:

```
external object MIDIjs {
    fun play(url: String, loop: Boolean = definedExternally)
    fun stop()
}
```

Call it in Kotlin exactly the same way, without the semicolon.

```
MIDIjs.play(url, true)
```

Comment: Good stuff. I hate when the docs fail to mention very useful things.

Answer (score 1):

Correct, there's no loop function (that's documented anywhere [here](http://www.midijs.net/midijs_api.html)).

However, we can at least simulate it with `MIDIjs.player_callback`, which is called every 100ms with an object that looks like `{ time : number }`. This is time in seconds elapsed. We can combine this with `get_duration` to detect the end of playback.

```js
function playAutoReset(url)
{
    // get_duration requires a callback as it returns nothing.
    MIDIjs.get_duration(url, function (duration)
    { 
        console.info(`Duration: ${duration}`);
        // Start the initial play
        MIDIjs.play(url);
        
        // This lets us keep track of current play time in seconds
        MIDIjs.player_callback = function (mes)
        {
            if (mes.time / duration >= 1)
            {
                console.info('End reached');
                // This plays the audio again
                MIDIjs.play(url);
            }
        };
    });
}
```

### Note:

This does call `play` each time, so it will probably re-download the source (the docs seem to imply that this is always the case). If you want something more network-efficient, you may want to look into XHRs/AJAX and creating an [object URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL), as the docs do specify that `play` takes a URL. However, I thought this would be the simplest solution, and it does show what you have to do to play the midi track again when it ends.